# Is there a function in c where I can copy specific parts of a char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have the char

```
char test[] = "Hello there\n"
              "World, my name\n"
              "Is bob\n";
```

Is there a function where I can use to store each line into a different char array. So the `\n` would indicate for me to stop, and store it into a new array? So in the end I would have 3 sets of char arrays. Essentially is there a function which I can use to find the `\n`, then copy everything before it, but then stop copying if it sees a `\n`

```
char line1[] = "Hello there\n";
char line2[] = "World, my name\n";
char line3[] = "Is bob\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtok as seen in the example below.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hello there\n"
              "World, my name\n"
              "Is bob\n";

    char *p;
    p = strtok(test, "\n");

    while(p) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I also ensure that `\n` also gets added into each line as well.